# Custom php autoloader

Tags: php, autoload

I'm trying to create a custom autoloader, which scans all directories and saves what classes are in each files.
This is all I have:

```
define ('PATH', 'C:\work\Symfony-1.4.20');

$files = array();
$map = array();

function loadClassLoader($name)
{
    global $map, $files;

    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(PATH)) as $file)
    { 
        $file2 = $file->__toString();

        if (strtolower($file2) != strtolower(__FILE__) && 
            $file->getExtension() == 'php' && 
            !isset($files[$file2]))
        {
            $files[$file2] = true;
            $classesNow = get_declared_classes();                    
            require ($file2);
            foreach (array_diff (get_declared_classes(), $classesNow) as $c)
            {
                $reflection = new ReflectionClass($c);
                $map[$c] = $reflection->getFileName();
                unset ($reflection);
            }            
        }
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('loadClassLoader');

loadClassLoader ('');

echo '<pre>'; var_dump ($map); echo '</pre>';
```

Sadly it wont work on bigger systems. What is missing from this logic?

The error message is: `Fatal error: Class 'BaseForm' not found in C:\Work\symfony-1.4.20\lib\form\addon\sfFormObject.class.php on line 20`

Comment: Please post the complete error message, even if you think it's irrelevant, and don't forget to highlight what line in your code it points to. Error messages are there to help you!

Comment: I dont mind... "Fatal error: Class 'BaseForm' not found in C:\Work\symfony-1.4.20\lib\form\addon\sfFormObject.class.php on line 20"